# Prevent value to negative numbers based on user input SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a table named tblitem now I want is when I add a product it will check the tblitem *stock* and if it is greater than the user input it will show an alert like *Insufficient Quantity*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//Getting Post Values
$itemname=$_POST['itemname']; 
$qty=$_POST['quantity'];   


$ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stock FROM tblitem WHERE ItemName ='$itemname' ");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
$latestinv = $row['stock'] - $qty; 

$updateq = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tblitem SET stock = '$latestinv' WHERE ItemName ='$itemname'");
$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tblpurchase(ItemName,Quantity,LatestInv) VALUES('$itemname','$qty','$latestinv')"); 

if($query){
echo "<script>alert('Product added successfully.');</script>";   
echo "<script>window.location.href='add-purchased.php'</script>";
}
 else{
echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');</script>"; 

}


}
```

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-10">
<label for="validationCustom03">Item</label>
 <select class="form-control custom-select" name="itemname" required>
<option value="">Select Item</option>
<?php
$rno=mt_rand(10000,99999);

$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select ItemName, stock from tblitem");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
{?> 

<option value="<?php echo $row['ItemName'];?>" <?php if($row['ItemName']=='stock'){echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $row['ItemName'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Please select Item.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Have you *tried anything* so far in that regard? Also, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection -- please consider using parameterised queries.

Comment: I'm new in php sir for the moment it's just a project sir but thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the stock values with the user entered quantity before adding of updating in table.

```
if($qty<=$row['stock']){   //Check the quantity value before inserting or updating
    $latestinv = $row['stock'] - $qty; 

    $updateq = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tblitem SET stock = '$latestinv' WHERE ItemName ='$itemname'");

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tblpurchase(ItemName,Quantity,LatestInv) VALUES('$itemname','$qty','$latestinv')");
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Entered quantity is greate than available stock');</script>"; 
}
```

Hope this will help you!